# What does "stand over against" mean here?

Tags: meaning

Never, in any earlier period, have the productive forces taken on a form so indifferent to the intercourse of individuals as individuals. On the other hand, **standing over against** these productive forces, we have the majority of the individuals from whom these forces have been wrested away, and who, robbed thus of all real life–content, have become abstract individuals, but who arc, however, only by this fact put into a position to enter into relations with one another as individuals.

Comment: I don't think it's a very good translation. Maybe Marx's original German was very convoluted anyway (I've no idea), but I think that sentence is pretty difficult for even well-schooled native Anglophones to parse properly! Turning specifically to the highlighted words though, I'd just assume the word ***over*** is superfluous, and leave it at that.

Comment: ...I'm guessing that *the majority of the individuals from whom [productive] forces have been wrested away* actually refers to ***workers*** (as opposed to ***bosses***), but quite what he's getting at by characterising them as ***abstract individuals*** is beyond me. It's not exactly English as I know it.